# Regular Expression in Java: How to refer to "matched patterns"?

Tags: java, regex

I was reading the Java Regular Expression tutorial, and it seems only to teach to test whether a pattern matched or not, but does not tell me how to refer to a matched pattern.

For example, I have a string "My name is xxxxx". And I want to print xxxx. How would I do that with Java regular expressions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What tutorial were you reading ? The sun's one tackles that topic quite thoroughly, but you have to read it correctly :)

Capturing a part of a string is done through the parentheses. If you want to capture a group in a string, you have to put this part of the regular expression in parentheses. The groups are defined in the order the parentheses appear, and the group with index 0 represents the whole string.

For instance, the regexp "*Day ([0-9]+) - Note ([0-9]+)*" would define 3 groups :

- *group(0)* : The whole string
- *group(1)* : The first group in the regexp, that is to say the day number
- *group(2)* : The second group in the regexp, that is to say the note number

As for the actual code and how to retrieve the groups you've defined in your regexp, have a look at the Java documentation, especially the Matcher class and its group method : http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html

You can test your regexps with that very useful tool : http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/General/RegexTester/regex-tester.html

Hope this helped, 
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Note the use of parentheses in the pattern and the `group()` method on `Matcher`

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Example {
    static public void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("My name is (.*)");
        String s = "My name is Michael";
        Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(s);

        if (matcher.matches()) {
            System.out.println("original string: " + matcher.group(0));
            System.out.println("first group: " + matcher.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
original string: My name is Michael
first group: Michael
```

Comment: I don't understand the concept of Group.
let's say I have a string "My name is Michael Jackson, his name is Barack Obama". And I want to capture "Michael Jackson" and "Barack Obama". how do i do it?

Comment: Ok. I got it. I got another harder one:

Did xxx xxx xxx (could be any number of words) live or die?

I want to capture: xxxxxx, live, die.

How do i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Matcher`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) [`group(int)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29) method:

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("My name is (.*)");
  Matcher m = p.matcher("My name is akf");
  m.find();
  String s = m.group(1); //grab the first group*
  System.out.println(s);
```

output:

```
akf
```

* look at [matching groups](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cg)

Answer (score 0):

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("name is (.*)").matcher("My name is Ross");
if (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group(0));
  System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

The parens form a *capturing group*. Group 0 is the entire pattern and group 1 is the *back reference*.

The above program outputs:

```
name is Ross
Ross
```